# I am the smallest, only a hand

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, language

> I am the smallest part, only a hand, yet I stand in front of the Almighty.
>
> Before water, I am a sea, yet I live in a city.
>
> I am the tenth, and the one after me can hold things.

What am I?

Note that I used the [language](/questions/tagged/language) tag on this. This riddle requires knowledge of a language other than English, though only at a basic level. Any answer should mention what language is being referenced here. Otherwise, the answer has no meaning.

Comment: There are many languages in the world. Maybe a hint?

Comment: It is a Middle-Eastern language.

Comment: I guess it is a bit too much to do some lateral thinking about an unknown language. How does one know his/her mother language is the one needed to solve this puzzle? Is it an obvious answer or still far fetched?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What am i?

> The letter Yod (hebrew)

I am the smallest part

> It is the smallest letter

only a hand

> it looks like a hand

yet I stand in front of the Almighty.

> The most important of God's Names is the four-letter Name represented by the Hebrew letters **Yod**-Hei-Vav-Hei (**Y**HVH)

Before water, I am a sea, yet I live in a city.

> Water = MA**Y**IM
>  Sea = **Y**AM
>  City = QIR**Y**AH

I am the tenth

> The letter Yod is the 10th letter of the Hebrew language

and the one after me can hold things.

> The next letter is Kaf, which means palm/grip

Comment: Finally, after weeks of crushing my head!! Thanks for this challenge.

Comment: This is it. YVW. I enjoyed writing this. Great work! More specifically, the letter derives from a proto-Semtic glyph that signified a hand.

Answer (score 3):

> A second?

I am the smallest part, only a hand, yet I stand in front of the Almighty.

> The Second hand in a clock is usually the thinnest. Yet, I stand in front of the Almighty/One

Before water, I am a sea, yet I live in a city.

> Maybe related to Greenwich

I am the tenth, and the one after me can grab things.

> "tenth" could probably be referring to the sexagesimal (base-60) positional numeral system. A hand can grab things.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! It's customary here to hide answers and explanations using spoiler tags (put `>!` before each line), so as not to spoil the solution for anyone else who wants to have a go at the puzzle. This is a pretty good answer, though.

Comment: This isn't it. Good try, though! Note that I included the language tag on this question. This question requires knowing some basics about a specific (non-English) language.

Comment: "The one *after* me" is significant. There is the one mentioned in the riddle, plus *another* thing that comes *after* that thing, possibly in some sort of sequence, order, or enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

Not a full answer, but may spark more interest.  I think you may be

> Hamsa

I am the smallest part,

> not sure

only a hand,

> The symbol for Hamsa is a hand

yet I stand in front of the Almighty.

> the symbol stands for the hand of God

Before water, I am a sea,

> Hamsa means sacred swan, which are said to live in Manasa Saras, a divine lake in Himilaya

yet I live in a city.

> not sure...

I am the tenth,

> Hamsa is one aspect of the tenth incarnation of Vishnu

and the one after me can hold things.

> Not sure on this one. Perhaps Kurma, another incarnation who is holding several items.

The language in this case is probably:

> Sanskrit

Comment: Sanskrit is not a Middle-Eastern language.

Answer (score 1):

I am the smallest part, only a hand, yet I stand in front of the Almighty.

> It's the smallest part of the wave of the sea.

Before water, I am a sea, yet I live in a city.

> Lives in the beach of the cities.

I am the tenth, and the one after me can grab things.

> The tide that comes after the last one drags things towards the sea.

What am I ?

> The Tide

Comment: I wouldn't say this really *lives* in a city.

Comment: @Randal'Thor It's always present(all days of the year) in cities with beachs.I'm also thinking about river,rain or cloud but I do not know.

Comment: This isn't it. Good try.

Answer (score 1):

What am I ?

> Day of Ashura

I am the smallest part, only a hand, yet I stand in front of the Almighty.

> according to the Quran "And nothing is hidden from your Lord (so much as) the weight of an atom on the earth or in the heaven" (Islam related)

Before water, I am a sea, yet I live in a city.

> Water in the Holy Quran In Islam, life and knowledge originated from water, but possibly you are referring to zamzam well (located in Mecca [a city]) (islam related)

I am the tenth,

> Ashura is a Muslim religious celebration that falls on the tenth day ofMuharram (the first month of the Islamic year) in the Islamic calendar. On this day Muslims are prohibited from eating, drinking and engaging in conjugal sexual relationships from dawn to sunset.

and the one after me can grab things.

> At the end of Ramadan there’s a big three-day celebration called Eid alFitr, or the Festival of the Breaking of the Fast. It's kind of like the Muslim version of Christmas, in the sense that it's a religious holiday where everyone comes together for big meals with family and friends, exchanges presents, and generally has a lovely time.

Comment: This isn't it. Good try, though. The "hand" thing is important. It is not necessarily a *literal* hand, but it is a hand nonetheless in some way.

Comment: i was so sure :(